# Car body cleaning is a tedious job

Tags: cleaning, body

I live in part of the world where dust is a very serious issue. I get my car washed and can find lot of dust on body within hours.

Is there any easy and cheap method to clean car body?

Comment: Except for washing, no. You may want to look at getting one of those covers that you can pull over your car. Like this: http://www.carcoverzone.co.uk/images/car_cover_waterproof_101.jpg

Comment: i live in India , it gets pretty dusty here, we hired people whom we pay a monthly sum and they clean our cars in the parking lot when we are at work (not washing , just wiping with cloth everyday, i know this is not a solution to your problem but it seems to give employment to someone and keeps your car clean. All I am saying is that if you can arrange someone like that at your work place it would be a win win situation.

Comment: I am adding this as a comment because it is not really a "solution": it may be practical just to have the car painted a matte color (light gray, or sand color). Dust just does not show up on this type of surface - unlike the glossy blacks that look perfect in the show room, but somehow never quite look clean in the street. Light colors are also slightly cooler in hot climates (I have been at 35-37 C all this week in Southwest Europe).

Answer (score 3):

There is a product called the [California Car Duster](http://www.calcarduster.com/products.asp) which allows you to pull off the dust without damaging the finish. I also found [this article](http://www.autogeekonline.net/forum/hot-topics-frequently-asked-questions/29355-static-electricity-dust-attraction-your-car-s-paint.html) on AutoGeekOnline.com which gives the basics of *why static electricity happens*. It basically states there is no way to get around the attraction of dust to paint, but gives some ways to help mitigate some of the effects. Other than that, washing is your next best option.

(PS: I like the @JuannStrauss suggestion of a car cover as well, especially if you don't have a garage.)

Answer (score 3):

Although its impossible to keep your car clean all the time without effort you can follow the below steps to keep it somewhat tidy avoiding the whole cleaning conundrum.

- Try to park away from trees, they attract dust, leaves, twigs and bird droppings.(if you want shade , use car cover.)
- When driving over puddles , drive slowly ,avoiding splashes near the wheel arches.
- If possible after a drive on a rainy day, hosing down the car with clean water will avoid the dirt from solidifying and more importantly will avoid rusting.
- Avoid driving with the windows down as the dust will clog on the fabric on the roof of the car which is a pain to get rid off.(May god save you if you have beige interiors , kidding)
- often clean the central console with a cloth , gives clean look to the passengers and you.
- Clean the windscreen as often as possible , signs of a clean car.
- Clean the wheel caps and alloys, functions same as the above point.
- Wash the car cover, many people don't realise that a dirty car cover will actually defeat the purpose of covering the car.

Answer (score 2):

After washing and drying the car, apply one or more coats of car polish and finishing / sealing wax.  You will find this makes the paintwork "slippery" and makes it more difficult for the dust to stick to the paintwork.

Comment: Thanks @Steve Matthews, I do get my car polished. But the environment where I am leaving is so dusty that I have to wipe my car's body approx. 5 times a day. And car requires washing once in two or three days. So I need help if there is some easy and cheap method to clean my car.